# Why Don't Medium Duty and Heavy Duty Trucks require Airbags?

Tags: safety, truck, supplemental-restraint-system

Why Don't Medium Duty and Heavy Duty Trucks require Airbags?

According to GSO 42 regulation, Passenger Cars, MPV, Trucks or Buses with GVW less than 3500Kg requires an airbag, while for MDT & HDT Trucks, there is no such requirements.

Why So?

Don't Heavy vehicle require airbag since they have greater momentum while impact compared to Lighter vehicles?

Comment: Perhaps the regulations looked at speed : cars tend to travel faster also, cars drivers are not required to respect driving hours, compulsory rest breaks etc

Comment: Also, you talk about greater momentum during impact, which means more of the force is going to impact the vehicle getting hit and not the driver of the  MDT or HDT.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about laws and regulations, not motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Comment: @paulster2, consider it hitting a wall. You got my point.

Comment: @paulster2, I read your other answer where you had explained about the reasons why airbags are not needed in racing cars today. +1 to that. I'm expecting similar explanation for this.

Comment: Instead of momentum, consider kinetic energy of the MDT or HDT. The object getting hit is going to take a lot more of the force than with a smaller vehicle. Also, consider the angle of the steering wheel. In a car, the wheel, and therefore the airbag, is pointed mainly at the driver's chest. In an HDT/MDT, the steering wheel points towards the ceiling for the most part. If an air bag were to deploy, it would only catch the face of the driver, which would probably kill them outright. Legally? No clue why they'd not enforce one.

Comment: You are confusing government regulations with logic; they have little connection.

Comment: @SanthanSalai, I've seen what happens when a heavy-duty truck hits a wall: the wall takes the brunt of the damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airbags protect the moving occupant against the sudden deceleration of the vehicle. Trucks usually hit objects that are lighter in mass. The truck's energy is transfered to the other vehicle, so the truck decelerates slowly.
Even if the truck hits a wall, the large mass and crumple zone means slower deceleration. The occupant can be protected by only lap/shoulder belts.

Answer (score 2):

Medium and Heavy Duty trucks are expected to be "work" trucks, not grocery go-getters. Drivers of work trucks are expected to be wearing personal protective equipment (PPE). An airbag can cause serious injury if the occupant is wearing PPE.